# AutoCADのスライドファイル(*.sld)を.Netで使う方法

Tags: .net, autocad, ijcad

業務でAutoLISPで使用していたプログラムを.Netへ移植することになりました。
＃AutoCADか互換のIJCADは現在検討中です。

旧システムでは、ダイアログ(DCL)でスライドファイル(*.sld)を使用していましたが、
WindowsFormで画面を再構築することにしたのですが、スライドファイルを使用するI/Fが
見つけられませんでした。

.Netでスライドを使用する場合、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？
可能な限りAutoLISP、DCLは使用したくありません。

以上です。

Answer (score 0):

AutoLispから使用するもののようで、.NetとしてのI/Fは存在しないようですね。

利用する場合、自前で読み取りBitmap等の画像クラスへ置き換える必要がありそうです。
フォーマット自体は公開されているようなので、参考としてURLを書いておきます。

https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/slide_files_dxf_aa.htm

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事に.NetでSLDファイルやSLBファイルをロードして.NetのBitmapに変換するコードがあります。

https://cadkhan.blogspot.com/2019/10/slideimagereadercs.html